# How MS Visio models stored in database?

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, visio, business-process-management, aris

We are using ARIS(BPM tool) for designing business process models with oracle. Now we want to move out of ARIS & migrate data in MS Visio. Is it possible to migrate data & start with MS Visio? How database is configured in MS Visio?

Comment: Depends on what version with Visio as there was a BPMN component available in some configurations. There are also commercial add-ins available. ARIS should export in the standard XML-based format (can't remember the exact name of it now) and some of the add-ins can import that standard format. This answers your key question about migrating the information.

Comment: Visio (out of the box) does not have any database backend; so it's not quite clear where you want to migrate your ARIS data exactly. You'll need some extension to Visio to make it happen. I would probably recommend you stick with ARIS unless you have strong reasons for migration.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a dedicated BPM-Addin for Visio, you'll probably need to rebuild the diagrams by means of code.
You'll need the position, the connections, the type of shape (operation) and finally the text displayed.